# Logo not showing in AppBar (Material UI / React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The logo is not showing on my AppBar for some reason. Here's what I am getting:

[image: Screenshot of the current AppBar]

This is my code:

```
import {
    AppBar,
    Toolbar,
    Typography,
    makeStyles,
    Button,
    IconButton,
    Drawer,
    Link,
    MenuItem,
  } from "@material-ui/core";
  import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
  import logo from '../overland-ninja-logo.png'; 
  
  const headersData = [
    {
      label: "Listings",
      href: "/listings",
    },
    {
      label: "Mentors",
      href: "/mentors",
    },
    {
      label: "My Account",
      href: "/account",
    },
    {
      label: "Log Out",
      href: "/logout",
    },
  ];
  
  const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    header: {
      backgroundColor: "#400CCC",
      paddingRight: "79px",
      paddingLeft: "118px",
      "@media (max-width: 900px)": {
        paddingLeft: 0,
      },
    },
    logo: {
      fontFamily: "Work Sans, sans-serif",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#FFFEFE",
      textAlign: "left",
    },
    menuButton: {
      fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
      fontWeight: 700,
      size: "18px",
      marginLeft: "38px",
    },
    toolbar: {
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
    },
    drawerContainer: {
      padding: "20px 30px",
    },
  }));
  
  export default function Header() {
    const { header, logo, menuButton, toolbar, drawerContainer } = useStyles();
  
    const [state, setState] = useState({
      mobileView: false,
      drawerOpen: false,
    });
  
    const { mobileView, drawerOpen } = state;
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const setResponsiveness = () => {
        return window.innerWidth < 900
          ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
          : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
      };
  
      setResponsiveness();
  
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
    }, []);
  
    const displayDesktop = () => {
      return (
        <Toolbar className={toolbar}>
          {femmecubatorLogo}
          <div>{getMenuButtons()}</div>
        </Toolbar>
      );
    };
  
    const displayMobile = () => {
      const handleDrawerOpen = () =>
        setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, drawerOpen: true }));
      const handleDrawerClose = () =>
        setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, drawerOpen: false }));
  
      return (
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            {...{
              edge: "start",
              color: "inherit",
              "aria-label": "menu",
              "aria-haspopup": "true",
              onClick: handleDrawerOpen,
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
  
          <Drawer
            {...{
              anchor: "left",
              open: drawerOpen,
              onClose: handleDrawerClose,
            }}
          >
            <div className={drawerContainer}>{getDrawerChoices()}</div>
          </Drawer>
  
          <div>{femmecubatorLogo}</div>
        </Toolbar>
      );
    };
  
    const getDrawerChoices = () => {
      return headersData.map(({ label, href }) => {
        return (
          <Link
            {...{
              component: RouterLink,
              to: href,
              color: "inherit",
              style: { textDecoration: "none" },
              key: label,
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem>{label}</MenuItem>
          </Link>
        );
      });
    };
  
    const femmecubatorLogo = (
      <img src={logo} />
    );
  
    const getMenuButtons = () => {
      return headersData.map(({ label, href }) => {
        return (
          <Button
            {...{
              key: label,
              color: "inherit",
              to: href,
              component: RouterLink,
              className: menuButton,
            }}
          >
            {label}
          </Button>
        );
      });
    };
  
    return (
      <header>
        <AppBar className={header}>
          {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
        </AppBar>
      </header>
    );
  }
```

I am quite new to react and I am sort of confused about how to go about this. I have tried all the tutorials but can't find the right solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are reassigning the value of `logo` to the output of `makeStyles().logo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning the value of `logo` after importing the image.

```
import logo from "../overland-ninja-logo.png"; // value of logo is correctly assigned to a path to the image
...
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  logo: {
    fontFamily: "Work Sans, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: "#FFFEFE",
    textAlign: "left"
  },
}));
...
const { header, logo, menuButton, toolbar, drawerContainer } = useStyles(); // value of logo is incorrectly assigned to a an object
```

If you are using vscode, you should get a typescript warning at `import logo`:

> 'logo' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)